# Two lines in IEEEpubid

Tags: ieeetran

I have a paper in `IEEEtran` style, on which I'm supposed to add the copyright. I did as follows, after the `\begin{document}`:

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-4799-5500-8/14/\$31.00 \copyright 2014 IEEE \hfill } 
\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{\hfill }}
```

Now the problem is, the editor wants the name and location of the conference to appear on a line right before this copyright line (and still everything aligned under the left column). How can I do that?

Comment: You don't need to put it. It's placed by the automatic pdf processor. Your editor must be confusing it by something else or you are reading the copy editor's specifications that are not meant for you. That is a journal pubid, a conference doesn't have such identifiers. But if you insist put without the makebox, `\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$20.00 \copyright 2012 IEEE}`

Comment: I do have to add it, the conference organizers sent a mail to the author for that. Unfortunately they didn't say how. The makebox is here so that it is aligned with the left column. Otherwise it is in the middle.

Comment: Another day, another strangeness from them. I would just mail them and ask for it specifically if they are so keen on it. IEEE doesn't necessarily follows this strange behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap the information in a `minipage`

```
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[12pt]
  978-1-4799-5500-8/14/\$31.00 \copyright 2014 IEEE\\ 
  Conference Name and venue
\end{minipage}}
```

Comment: When doing that, the lines simply aren't there at all.

Comment: it seems that the text in `\IEEEpubid` overlaps the text in the body of the paper. I have edited the text with a simple hack to prevent the problem.

Comment: In fact, the problem with a missing \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts. Works perfectly now, thank you very much :-)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. For me it needed an extra \centering inside the minipage to make it proper.