# Problem with copyright notice within ieeeconf template

Tags: ieeeconf

I'd just checked a great deal of related questions, corresponding to similar problems, such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230111/add-a-copyright-and-a-title-in-a-latex-paper), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55813/how-to-add-copyright-notice-in-a-box-with-borders-at-bottom-of-first-page), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191438/two-lines-in-ieeepubid), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146227/how-to-avoid-overflow-using-ieeepubid-on-the-first-column) and so on; But all of them lead to below error:

```
Undefined Control Sequence \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts\IEEEpubid...
```

Here is the kernel of my template file' code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              

\overrideIEEEmargins                                      

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{\LARGE \bf
My Papr's Title
}

\author{Me$^{1}$ and Someone Else$^{2}$% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$My Affiliation
        {\tt\small my email address}}%
\thanks{$^{2}$Her Affiliation
        {\tt\small her email address}}%
}

\makeatletter
    \setlength\@fptop{0\p@}
\makeatother

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-4799-4937-3/14/\$31.00~\copyright{}2014 IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}

\begin{document}

%\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{\hfill 9781-4244-3941-6/09/\$25.00~\copyright~2009 IEEE}
%\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\section*{Acknowledgment}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1}
V.~Braitenberg. \textit{Vehicles. Experiments in synthetic psychology}. The MIT Press, 1984.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Would you please guide me to insert the copyright notice, deservedly?

Comment: The class is actually called `IEEEconf.cls`, MikTeX won't complain, but Linux/Unix/Mac user have to edit this :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I'm just compiling the file with MikTeX 2.9 on windows 10. So.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the other answers and using `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` after `\begin{document}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` is provided by `IEEEtran.cls` and not `IEEEconf.cls`. `\overrideIEEEmargins` is not supported in version 1.7+.

`\bf` ought not be used in LaTeX which deprecated it 20+ years ago. Be careful not to introduce spurious spaces in, for example, titles etc.

For example,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\title{\LARGE \bfseries My Paper's Title}% \bf was deprecated 20+ years ago and ought not be used in LaTeX

\author{Me$^{1}$ and Someone Else$^{2}$% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$My Affiliation
        {\tt\small my email address}}%
\thanks{$^{2}$Her Affiliation
        {\tt\small her email address}}%
}

\makeatletter
    \setlength\@fptop{0\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% \overrideIEEEmargins is no longer supported
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-4799-4937-3/14/\$31.00~\copyright{}2014 IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\section*{Acknowledgment}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1}
V.~Braitenberg. \textit{Vehicles. Experiments in synthetic psychology}. The MIT Press, 1984.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

compiles without error:

[image: compiled version]

Comment: Thanks in advance... Actually, the usage of `bf` was due to its native embodiment within the template, but thanks for the advice about its deprecation. Could we conclude that `ieeetran` will cover `ieeeconf` in an extensive manner, leading to deprecation of the latter, gradually?!

Comment: @Roboticist I have no idea. Better ask IEEE?

Comment: Sure... I guessed any guess would be stemmed from your long-time experience within working with such packages... Your kindness for the contribution.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used an IEEE class myself, so I have absolutely no experience to draw on ;).